# JSF2 Form Authentication with database users

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, forms-authentication, j-security-check

I'm currently using JSF 2 and icefaces framework for JavaScript.

I'm having some problems with j_security_check based on the url(that's not the point), that my taste is very strict
my question is:
Is there any better way of authentication, or some alternative? I find JAAS, but did not convince me because the users are stored in a database table.

At the moment I did not use any other framework as a seam or spring, I think I'll complicate my life a little, since I am a noob.

However, any suggestion is welcome, if you show how, I am willing to try, I want to learn =D

Answer (score 1):

I see that what bothers you is the fact that

> the users are stored in a database
>   table

You can save a list in XML or properties file and read it from there.

Comment: kind of, i have some problem because the url don't refresh itself when i'm browsing example i go from the index to search and the url still index and then return to index and the url changes to search and then j_security_check plays
Just want to know if there's an alternative way to do it

Comment: In other words, you want to redirect to and from the j_security_check request instead of forward it? This behaviour is servletcontainer specific and not configureable. Your best bet is homegrowing it. Have a look at Filters.

Comment: yeah, I heard about filters, but I haven't researched much about it, i'll take a look thx